# Prove the inequality $\frac{a+c}{a+b}+\frac{b+d}{b+c}+\frac{c+a}{c+d}+\frac{d+b}{d+a}\geq 4$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$a, b, c, d$ are positive reals.
How would I prove the inequality
$$\frac{a+c}{a+b}+\frac{b+d}{b+c}+\frac{c+a}{c+d}+\frac{d+b}{d+a} \geq 4$$

I have tried using the rearrangement inequality with $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$
But it doesn't seem to work well.
Any hints please?

Comment: You _could_ try the hard way, and add all those fractions up and see what you get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\frac{\color{blue}{a+c}}{a+b}+\frac{\color{red}{b+d}}{b+c}+\frac{\color{blue}{c+a}}{c+d}+\frac{\color{red}{d+b}}{d+a}=\frac{\color{blue}{a+c}}{a+b}+\frac{\color{blue}{a+c}}{c+d}+\frac{\color{red}{b+d}}{b+c}+\frac{\color{red}{b+d}}{d+a}$$

$$\frac{\color{blue}{a+c}}{a+b}+\frac{\color{blue}{a+c}}{c+d}+\frac{\color{red}{b+d}}{b+c}+\frac{\color{red}{b+d}}{d+a}=(\color{blue}{a+c})\color{green}{\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}\right)}+(\color{red}{b+d})\color{brown}{\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}\right)}$$

WLOG  $$\color{brown}{\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}} \ge \color{green}{\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}}  $$

Then

$$(\color{blue}{a+c})\color{green}{\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}\right)}+(\color{red}{b+d})\color{brown}{\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}\right)} \ge (\color{blue}{a+c}+\color{red}{b+d})\color{green}{\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}\right)}$$ $$= (\color{turquoise}{a+b}+\color{orange}{c+d})\left(\color{turquoise}{\frac{1}{a+b}}+\color{orange}{\frac{1}{c+d}}\right) \ge (1+1)^2=4$$

Comment: Well THAT seems very short, considering how much I actually had to type.

Comment: Your edit was really quite clever!  (+1)

Comment: Was your last step something on the lines of $$\Big((\sqrt{a+b})^2 + (\sqrt{c+d})^2\Big)\Big(\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+d}}\Big)^2\Big) \ge (1+1)^2$$ from Cauchy Schwartz or something simpler?

Comment: @AritraDas That's basically what it was. I don't think it can get much simpler.

Comment: To do simpler, from line 2 use $\frac1{a+b}+\frac1{c+d}=\frac4{a+b+c+d}$ and you have it.  Good one though, +1.

Comment: I get the idea of the proof, but I don't get the 'WLOG' part...I understood everything else. Can you give me a further explanation?

Comment: @zxcvber It basically means without loss of generality. It is clear that one of $$\color{brown}{\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}} \ge \color{green}{\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}}  $$  or $$\color{brown}{\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}} \le \color{green}{\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}}  $$has to be true. However, in the second case, the proof is basically the same as in the first case. So, I without loss of generality, assumed the first one was true.

Comment: Oh I thought it was something to do with a, b, c, d. Didn't think of it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{a+b}=(a+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}\right)+(b+d)\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d+a}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{4(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}+\frac{4(b+d)}{b+c+d+a}=4.$$